# Unrecognized mexmaci64 file in MatLab

Tags: c++, c, matlab, mex

I am trying to use a .mexmaci64 function in MatLab. This function is working on the (Mac) machine of the person who compiled the .mexmaci64 file.

MatLab R2021a on my Windows 10 machine gives me the common error: `Unrecognized function or variable 'filename'.` for a file named "filename.mexmaci64". I have confirmed that:

1. The file name is correctly specified in the code (to match the file but without the `.mexmaci64` extension).
2. The file is located in the current working directory
3. The file is located within the path directory

Is this a Mac - Windows conversion issue? Do I need to recompile on my local machine?
Does anyone have any other recommendations aside from recompiling the function on my local machine?

Comment: Yes, `.mexmaci64` is a binary explicitly built for the mac (`i64` means Intel 64-bits, and `mac` means mac...). On Windows, MEX-files have an extension `.mexw64`. You will need to rebuild the MEX-file for Windows if it's not already available. See here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mexext.html

Comment: Thank you Cris, this is very helpful. In hindsight this extension name appears to be quite obvious! If you would like to post your comment as an answer, I can accept it.